# Что такое “оконные вставки” (window insets) в Android?

Tags: android

Самая лучшая статья, которую я нашла по этому вопросу - это [Defining Layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/layouts.html).
Но всё-таки хотелось бы удостовериться, что я правильно поняла этот термин. Правильно ли я понимаю, что "оконные вставки" это те области в круглом окне, которые не заняты квадратом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И, соответственно, у квадратных окон они всегда нулевые (их нет)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, Вы поняли термин не совсем верно. "Оконная  вставка",как Вы ее назвали, это в данном случае именно серая квадратная область где для примера выведен текст "Hello there!". Серый квадрат на данном рисунке показывает область где  BoxInsetLayout может автоматически разместить все view, которые определены внутри него, после того как сам подстроится под размеры круглого экрана. BoxInsetLayout позволяет написать один код который будет корректно отображать view как для квадратных так и для круглых экранов.